# Split string into array of exactly two parts when a number is encountered

Tags: javascript, string, split, text-manipulation

Is there a way to split a string into an array of exactly two parts when a number is encountered (preferably using `split()`)?

Examples:

- `"Nutritional Value per 100 gram"` ==> `["Nutritional Value per", "100 gram"]`
- `"Protein (g) 4.27"` ==> `["Protein (g)", "4.27"]`

Comment: split with regex

Comment: You could also substring from 0 to the index of the first number - 1.  And then substring from that last index + 1 for the second part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/ (?=\d+)/` to split on a space followed by a sequence of digit characters:

```js
console.log(["Nutritional Value per 100 gram", "Protein (g) 4.27"]
  .map(s => s.split(/ (?=\d+)/)));
```

If you want to generalize this and not rely on the presence of a space before the digit sequence, try:

```js
console.log(["Nutritional Value per100 gram", "Protein (g)4.27", "0a11b 2.2cc3"]
  .map(s => [...s.matchAll(/^\D+|(?:\d[\d.]*\D*)/g)]));
```

Comment: I tried that, but it also splits the at the decimal sign - when you run it on "Protein (g) 4.27" it returns  ["Protein (g)", "4", "27"] instead of  ["Protein (g)", "4.27"]

Comment: See update. I tried to generalize a bit prematurely.

Comment: Works perfectly now.
Thank you. Wish I had asked earlier .

Answer (score 0):

You can get index of first num using reg exce. Then can split.

```js
const split = (str) => {
  const m = /\d/.exec(str);
  if (m) {
    const index = m.index;
    return [str.slice(0, index - 1), str.slice(index)];
  }
  return [str];
};
console.log(split("Nutritional Value per 100 gram"));
console.log(split("Protein (g) 4.27"));
// output: [ 'Nutritional Value per', '100 gram' ]
// output: [ 'Protein (g)', '4.27' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const splitFunt = (text) => {
    const arrValues = text.match(/([^\s]+)/g);
    let firstPart = '';
    let lastPart = '';
    for (let i in arrValues) {
      if (i <= arrValues.length / 2) {
       firstPart += arrValues[i] + ' ';
      } else {
       lastPart += arrValues[i] + ' ';
      }
    }
    return [firstPart, lastPart];
}

console.log(splitFunt('Nutritional Value per 100 gram'));
console.log(splitFunt('Protein (g) 4.27'));
```